# issue with NOT NULL in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

I am using `wamp` in `win 7`.

In my database, I have one table `be_users`, two fields: `username` and `email`, both of them are set `NOT NULL`.

But why I still can **`insert`** empty value and null value into field: email, see below image:
[image]

Comment: `NULL` is not the same as an empty string (in MySQL), and `NULL` is not the same as the string `'null'`.

Comment: it "null" string ! I think! please check

Comment: If **`'null'`** is passed as in **Quotes** then **Yes**.

Comment: NULL and 'null' are two different things bro. 'null' is string like any email address or username 'maulikvora'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are inserting text and they are not `NULL`. The text `NULL` is very different from *NULL*. You can never violate the rule if the field is set to `NOT NULL`.

Try executing this statement,

```
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (null, null)  -- will fail
```

it will surely fail because those are `NULL`. But this statement below will surely work because you are inserting `string`.

```
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('', 'null')  -- will work
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty value does not equal NULL, and it looks like you are inserting 'null' not NULL into the database, so you are ending up with a string 'null' not a NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

Dont send NULL enclosed with quotes 'NULL' or "NULL" its getting treated as text value.

the issue is due to the data type used for thease two field. "text" you can change this to varchar(255) to use NULL. There are some issue with NULL and data type text.

Answer (score 0):

`Null` is a keyword. If you will enter null directly then it will show you error.

Example-

```
insert into tablename(fieldname) values(null);
```

This above line will generate error(if you have mentioned `not null`).

I think you have enter something else. Please check again the table structure and enter new data.